# Random effect decomposition with glmer(lme4)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to simulate a dataset with random effects. But I'm not sure how to estimate nested variance and relation between nested effects and the sub-effects within.

My question (based on the glmer model, I know in linear model, the variance is not correctly specified may go to the residual):

1. if there are nested effects(based on the data nature/experiment design) but my model doesn't contain nested structure. For example: class is nested within school (1 | school/class) in model 1 but model 2 is (1 | class) supposed that I didn't specify model structure correctly, will the variance(class) in model 2 be equal to variance(class) + variance(school) in model 2?
2. What's the relationship between the nested random effects and the random effects within(level 1)?

Thanks in advance. Any clarification would be appreciated.